# Cannot get correct query keep getting duplications

Tags: oracle, join, subquery

I am not able to get the correct query.
I have three tables 
A, B, and C.
A Has ID as a primary key and name as non primary key,
B Has ID as a primary key and StoreID as non primary key,
C Has ID as a primary key and name and number as non primary key.

I want to be able to display the name of A, and the name and number of C where A ID equals B ID and B Store ID equals C ID

Heres what I have

```
select a.name,c.name, c.number
from A a, C c
where a.ID IN
   (select ID
   from B
   where StoreID IN
      (select ID
      from C)
```

All the correct data shows up however it appears as there are many duplications with the name and number of C. It gives me all combinations of name and number with the data on the left side.

Comment: Can you show some sample data please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT      a.name, c.name, c.number
FROM        a
INNER JOIN  b ON a.ID = b.ID
INNER JOIN  c ON b.StoreID = c.ID
```